# input[type=image] почему появляется доп символы в url

Tags: html

Сделал кнопку из изображения но при нажатие на неё она добавляет в url координаты на которые я кликнул x и y, как от них избавиться? e.preventdefault(); не сработало

```
<input type="image" name="image" src="/img/button.png">
```

p.s Я знаю что можно просто как фон поставить картинку о простого button, вопрос больше на понимание событий браузера

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то она для того и нужна, чтобы координаты клика добавлять, так что нечего от них избавляться. Стилизуй нормальный button.